# single quote escape - sequelize migration

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using **NodeJS** with **Sequelize ORM** and **Postgress** database
I'm creating *ENUM* column named `education_level` in table using migration file as below and enum value (Bachelor's Degree) has single quote and it gives below error when i try to run migrations, Thank you for helping!

migration file

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Education', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      school: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      degree: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      field_of_study: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      year_started: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(4)
      },
      year_graduated: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(4)
      },
      education_level: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM,
        values: ['Diploma','Bachelor\'s Degree','Master\'s Degree','Doctorate Degree'],
      },
      profile_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Education');
  }
};
```

error

```
{ SequelizeBaseError: syntax error at or near "s"
migrate_1        |     at Query.formatError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:357:14)
migrate_1        |     at Query.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:88:19)
migrate_1        |     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
migrate_1        |     at Query.emit (events.js:191:7)
migrate_1        |     at Query.handleError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:108:8)
migrate_1        |     at Connection.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:171:26)
migrate_1        |     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
migrate_1        |     at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
migrate_1        |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:12)
migrate_1        |     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
migrate_1        |     at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
migrate_1        |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
migrate_1        |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
migrate_1        |     at TCP.onread (net.js:563:20)
migrate_1        |   name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
migrate_1        |   message: 'syntax error at or near "s"',
migrate_1        |   parent:
migrate_1        |    { error: syntax error at or near "s"
migrate_1        |        at Connection.parseE (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:539:11)
migrate_1        |        at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:366:17)
migrate_1        |        at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
migrate_1        |        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
migrate_1        |        at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
migrate_1        |        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
migrate_1        |        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
migrate_1        |        at TCP.onread (net.js:563:20)
migrate_1        |      name: 'error',
migrate_1        |      length: 90,
migrate_1        |      severity: 'ERROR',
migrate_1        |      code: '42601',
migrate_1        |      detail: undefined,
migrate_1        |      hint: undefined,
migrate_1        |      position: '84',
migrate_1        |      internalPosition: undefined,
migrate_1        |      internalQuery: undefined,
migrate_1        |      where: undefined,
migrate_1        |      schema: undefined,
migrate_1        |      table: undefined,
migrate_1        |      column: undefined,
migrate_1        |      dataType: undefined,
migrate_1        |      constraint: undefined,
migrate_1        |      file: 'scan.l',
migrate_1        |      line: '1086',
migrate_1        |      routine: 'scanner_yyerror',
migrate_1        |      sql: 'CREATE TYPE "public"."enum_Education_education_level" AS ENUM(\'Diploma\', \'Bachelor\'s Degree\', \'Master\'s Degree\', \'Doctorate Degree\');' },
migrate_1        |   original:
migrate_1        |    { error: syntax error at or near "s"
migrate_1        |        at Connection.parseE (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:539:11)
migrate_1        |        at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:366:17)
migrate_1        |        at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
migrate_1        |        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
migrate_1        |        at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
migrate_1        |        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
migrate_1        |        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
migrate_1        |        at TCP.onread (net.js:563:20)
migrate_1        |      name: 'error',
migrate_1        |      length: 90,
migrate_1        |      severity: 'ERROR',
migrate_1        |      code: '42601',
migrate_1        |      detail: undefined,
migrate_1        |      hint: undefined,
migrate_1        |      position: '84',
migrate_1        |      internalPosition: undefined,
migrate_1        |      internalQuery: undefined,
migrate_1        |      where: undefined,
migrate_1        |      schema: undefined,
migrate_1        |      table: undefined,
migrate_1        |      column: undefined,
migrate_1        |      dataType: undefined,
migrate_1        |      constraint: undefined,
migrate_1        |      file: 'scan.l',
migrate_1        |      line: '1086',
migrate_1        |      routine: 'scanner_yyerror',
migrate_1        |      sql: 'CREATE TYPE "public"."enum_Education_education_level" AS ENUM(\'Diploma\', \'Bachelor\'s Degree\', \'Master\'s Degree\', \'Doctorate Degree\');' },
migrate_1        |   sql: 'CREATE TYPE "public"."enum_Education_education_level" AS ENUM(\'Diploma\', \'Bachelor\'s Degree\', \'Master\'s Degree\', \'Doctorate Degree\');' }
api_migrate_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape that single quote with another single quote. So maybe this will work:

```
education_level: {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM,
    values: ['Diploma','Bachelor\'\'s Degree','Master\'\'s Degree','Doctorate Degree'],
  },
```

### Explanation

Initial query sent to server:

```
CREATE TYPE "public"."enum_Education_education_level" AS ENUM(
  'Diploma', 'Bachelor's Degree', 'Master's Degree', 'Doctorate Degree'
);
```

As you can see by syntax coloring, it does not see `'Bachelor's Degree'` as a single string, but rather `'Bachelor'` and then `s Degree'`. This happens because that escaped apostrophe was used to build string for JavaScript (apostropes escaped with backslash). It does not escape string for PostgreSQL.

In order to fix this, we need to escape that apostrophe on PostgreSQL side and since PostgreSQL uses apostrophe to escape apostrophe, we aim to get this:

```
CREATE TYPE "public"."enum_Education_education_level" AS ENUM(
  'Diploma', 'Bachelor''s Degree', 'Master''s Degree', 'Doctorate Degree'
);
```

So on JavaScript side we construct string with two escaped apostrophes `'Bachelor\'\'s Degree'`. JavaScript changes `\'\'` to `''` and PostgreSQL `''` to `'`.

Comment: Why do you have to do that?

Comment: @7hibault If you see query that was sent to server in any editor that has syntax highlighting you will notice that apostrophe delimits string too early: `CREATE TYPE "public"."enum_Education_education_level" AS ENUM('Diploma', 'Bachelor's Degree', 'Master's Degree', 'Doctorate Degree');`. First escape was meant for the programming language used, second is for PostgreSQL server.

Comment: @7hibault You are welcome. I've edited my answer with a bit more detailed explanation of why this is needed and how it works.